Replace functionality of flutter_helper package (discontinued) to use tflite model in flutter code
tflite_flutter_helper package has been discontinued, which had provided functions to facilitate pre-processing of camera image before feeding it into the tflite model to run pose estimations. My code was running fine building ImageProcessor
imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
    .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(padSize, padSize))
    .add(ResizeOp(192, 192, ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
    .build();

output TensorBufferFloat
outputLocations = TensorBufferFloat([1, 1, 17, 3]);

and inputImage to tflite
inputImage = TensorImage(TfLiteType.float32);

all of which is defunct now, since the package containing these functionalities (tflite_flutter_helper) is discontinued. I am stuck without any alternate package now, and coding all of the functionalities seems a bit daunting to me.
Please help me tackle this challenge!
I have tried searching for alternate flutter sdks with no luck, and as I mentioned before, coding for the pre-processing seems out of my scope as of now.
